# Powershell: Can't store the output from Invoke-Expression in a variable

Tags: powershell

I've got a fairly lengthy Powershell script that I'd like to call from another script.  Currently, I'm using Invoke-Expression to make this call, and it works well:

```
    $argumentList = @()
    $argumentList += ("-oldaccount", ($oldDomain + "\" + $oldUname), "-newaccount", ($newDomain + "\" + $newUname))

    $output = Invoke-Expression "C:\path\to\script.ps1 $argumentList"
```

The script that I'm calling writes its output lines to the screen using Write-Host.  I'd like to capture this output in the caller script so that I can put it in a log file, and ideally I'd like to do this without modifying the script that I'm calling.  I've tried the suggestion in [How to pipe output of Invoke-Expression to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320275/how-to-pipe-output-of-invoke-expression-to-string) with no luck - when I run the code in ISE, I just get the output to the screen and the variable stays empty.  Do I need to do something different since I'm calling another Powershell script and not an executable?

Comment: Write-Host does not send anything to the Pipe. That is specifically why it exists. Write-Output will write to the pipe.

Comment: Makes sense.  I'll change the Write-Hosts to Write-Outputs.  Thanks!

Comment: PS: You don't need to use Invoke-Expression: $output = C:\path\to\script.ps1 -oldaccount ($oldDomain + "\" + $oldUname) -newaccount ($newDomain + "\" + $newUname)

Answer (score 1):

Write-Host will not work for you. Try returning a value in your inner script for example:

InnerScript.ps1 could be:

```
return "Test"
```

And then OuterScript.ps1 should be:

```
$output = Invoke-Expression ".\InnerScript.ps1"
```

Write-Host($output) should show:

```
Test
```

Adapt this example to your specific scenario. Hope it helps.