# Getting the result of a Invoked-Expression in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to test some archives in a Powerhsell script as I am automating the compression of a bunch of backup files with `7z`.

Now I know that normally when a program runs it returns 0 if everything completed normally; but will return some other value if it did not complete normally.

For example we see here in `Scheduled Tasks` that the Last Result displays `0x0` when the task completes successfully, and other values if it did not.

[image: Scheduled Tasks window with the Last Result column displaying 0x0 at successful tasks and 0x5 for non successful tasks (though it could be another value for unsuccessful tasks)]

When I use `Invoke-Expression` in Powershell to run `7z` to test the archive, I need to be able to pull the program return value to make sure that the archive tested successfully; is there any way to get this value from `Invoke-Expression`?

I'm calling the following command from Invoke-Expression:

```
7z t C:\backups\somezip.7z *.* -r
```

Also what is the value I'm talking about called?  I know that if you write a program in C++ you return the value from the `main` method, but I'm not certain what it is called.

Comment: Can I ask why you might be using Invoke-Expression? Do you know for sure that you need it? The following might also help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320275/how-to-pipe-output-of-invoke-expression-to-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320275/how-to-pipe-output-of-invoke-expression-to-string)

Comment: @FLGMwt What's a good reason for using `Invoke-Expression`?  Spaces in the path within the called command?

Comment: @FLGMwt I'm not interested in the output, I'm interested in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose the paths in speechmarks ie

`& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" t "C:\backups\somezip.7z" *.* -r`

and the value you are looking for is called `$LASTEXITCODE`.