# PowerShell MySQL Backup Script Error in Task Scheduler 0x00041301

Tags: mysql, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, taskscheduler

I have created the following PowerShell script.

```
$root = 'C:\Backups\My Website\Database Dumps\'

$dateString = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$fileName = $dateString + "-MyWebsiteDbBackup.sql"

$backupFilePath = ($root + $fileName)

$command = ("mysqldump -u root wpdatabase > " + "`"$backupFilePath`"")

Write-Host $command

Invoke-Expression $command
```

Its function is supposed to be making a daily backup of a MySQL database for my WordPress website.

When I run the script in PowerShell ISE, it runs fine and the MySQL dump file is created with no problems.

However, in Task Scheduler, it was stuck on running with a code `0x00041301`.

For the credentials, I am using the `my.cnf` technique [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/mysqldump-without-the-password-prompt). And I've set the task to run whether a user is logged on or not.

**CODE UPDATE**

Based on vonPryz's answer.

```
$root = 'C:\Backups\My Website\Database Dumps\'

$dateString = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$fileName = $dateString + "-MyWebsiteDbBackup.sql"

$backupFilePath = ($root + $fileName + " 2>&1")

$command = ("mysqldump -u root wpdatabase > " + "`"$backupFilePath`"")

Write-Host $command

$output = Invoke-Expression $command 

$output | Out-File C:\mysqlBackupScriptOutput.txt
```

This now give me an error saying `illegal character in path`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note: `$dateString = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` would be more readable.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'll update it to that.

Comment: Remove the `2>&1` from the string you assign to $backupFilePath and see if you still get illegal chars (> is an illegal path char).

Comment: @KeithHill it is what [this suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320275/how-to-pipe-output-of-invoke-expression-to-string/12320512#12320512) I do.

Comment: You are doing a bit more here - specifically you put `$backupFilePath` in quotes which makes the whole string (including 2>&1) appear as part of the filename.  Well, that's my theory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler's code `0x00041301` [means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383604(v=vs.85).aspx) that the task is running. This is likely to mean that `mysqldump` is prompting for something. Maybe a password or some confirmation dialog. Which user account is the task being run on?

In order to debug, you'd need to capture the process' output to see what's going on. Try using [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) to send a copy to a file.

Comment: Thanks Von, if I do this at the end `Invoke-Expression $command | Tee-Object -FilePath "C:\commandoutput.txt" | Out-Null` will it create that text file? Or do I need to have that in place first?

Comment: Nope, looks like it doesn't. I'll try creating the file first.

Comment: Ok, that didn't help either. The `commandoutput.txt` was empty after I ran the task!

Comment: @Ciwan Hm, how about using `2>&1` to [send stderr to stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320512)? Get rid of the `|out-null` too, as it introduces unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Once I've placed it in an `$output` variable, then what? How would I write that to a file? I think `Tee-Object` doesn't do that right?

Comment: I think I figured out how to output a variable to a file, but getting a different error with regards to `2>&1` see updated Q.